# Java method vrs reference performance

Tags: java, methods, reference

I prefer to call a method as few times as possible due to the perception that I have that calling a method has a performance cost that is greater than the performance cost of calling it only once and keeping a reference. Problem is that I think I got this viewpoint from C++ back in college and things have changed a lot since then.

So which is cheaper?

```
something.getOrDoSomething();
something.getOrDoSomething();
```

or

```
Thing thing1 = something.getOrDoSomething();
//use thing1 from now on.
```

Now I'm aware that a method might contain anything so lets assume that they don't. They are just simple getters. Are there JVM performance optimizations I should be aware of?

I want to clear this up because I've been seeing it a lot in legacy code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're asking about performance: **It. Doesn't. Matter.**

JIT in JVM will optimize the bytecode at runtime and the execution of those options will be even faster than you think. Don't worry on this kind of micro optimizations unless it's proven this is a bottleneck in your application and demonstrated by the usage of a tool like a profiler.

From your comment:

> if developers get used to coding this way might not they eventually make repetitive calls to a method that does something more than just getting?

Here your concern is not only about performance. Here the answer would be: it's a matter of usefulness for the part of the code being used, or code readability:

- If you do very few calls on this getter through a piece of code and it's for small purposes, then use the getter.
- If you need to access to this field lot of times within a single piece of code and you need to debug through changes that are done to this reference, you will surely store it in a variable first, then use it.

Another factor to take into account is the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter):

> - Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only units "closely" related to the current unit.
> - Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers.
> - Only talk to your immediate friends.

This is, for example, having a piece of code like this:

```
public void someMethod(Foo foo) {
    logger.info(foo.getBar().getFirstName());
    logger.info(foo.getBar().getLastName());
    logger.info(foo.getBar().getBirthday());
    logger.info(foo.getBar().getBaz().getSomefield());
    //and probably more other operations not directly involved with logger.info...
}
```

It should be rewritten to:

```
public void someMethod(Foo foo) {
    Bar bar = foo.getBar();
    logger.info(bar.getFirstName());
    logger.info(bar.getLastName());
    logger.info(bar.getBirthday());
    Baz baz = bar.getBaz();
    logger.info(baz.getSomefield());
    //and on...
}
```

Comment: OK but if developers get used to coding this way might not they eventually make repetitive calls to a method that does something more than just getting? Exactly, how much cleanup do we want to do in Perf? What if we don't have a Perf? Not everybody is Google, right? You could be operating pretty close to the margin.

Comment: @user447607 again, it does not matter; you are talking Java here, so the rule of thumb is to write code which is obviously correct; the JIT will optimize it for you, and what is more, the JIT is smarter than you. Now, there are code conventions etc which can come into play.

Comment: @Durandal why? Call sites won't change, and the JIT may also elect to inline the code of the target method

Comment: @Durandal in terms of performance, it doesn't matter. But if you take into account other factors like code readability, then it does.

Comment: Nvm missed the "simple getter part", my bad.

Comment: OK so consensus seems to be that we don't do this for readability, Law of Demeter, etc. rather than performance since the JVM handles it OK. I want to comment about chaining too... whoops that's covered here too. Thanks guy!